# unrecognized option '-EL' android kernel build

Tags: android, linux, assembly, build, clang

I'm trying to build an android kernel. On every build I get a few errors:

- /usr/bin/as: unrecognized option '-EL' clang-16: error: assembler
  command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
- warning: field 'cgrp' with variable sized type 'struct cgroup' not at
  the end of a struct or class is a GNU extension
  [-Wgnu-variable-sized-type-not-at-end] struct group cgrp;
- warning: unused function 'dump_workqueue' [-Wunused-function] static
  void dump_workqueue(void) {}

I've already tried a lot. No more ideas and information on the Internet. Please help me how to solve this.

I use clang-r475365b and gcc android-11.0.0_r48
My Kernel: https://github.com/OnePlusOSS/android_kernel_oneplus_sm8250/tree/oneplus/SM8250_R_11.0

My build.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
if [[ -d "out" ]]
then
    cd out && make clean && make distclean && make mrproper && cd ..
else
    mkdir -p out
fi

make O=out ARCH=arm64 vendor/bengal-perf_defconfig

PATH="${HOME}/heh/Desktop/clang/bin:${HOME}/heh/Desktop/toolchains/bin${PATH}" \
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${HOME}/heh/Desktop/clang/lib:${HOME}/heh/Desktop/toolchains/lib${PATH}" \

make                  O=out \
                      ARCH=arm64 \
                      SUBARCH=arm64 \
                      CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-android- \
                      CROSS_COMPILER=$PATH \
                      CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- \
                      RANLIB=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-ranlib \
                      CC='/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/clang -fintegrated-as' \
                      AR=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-ar \
                      AS=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-as \
                      NM=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-nm \
                      OBJCOPY=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-objcopy \
                      OBJDUMP=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-objdump \
                      READELF=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-readelf \
                      OBJSIZE=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-size \
                      STRIP=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-strip \
                      -j4
```

I took it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66799641/usr-bin-as-unrecognized-option-el), but the solution presented there did not help

Comment: For whatever reason some part is invoking the host `/usr/bin/as`. You should look at what the current target is at that point. We can't help you because you did not post relevant information.

Comment: @Jester
This my log: 
https://pastebin.com/FZ6547FC

Comment: You should not use `-j4` because it makes reading logs hard. Anyway, it looks like what fails is `scripts/mod/empty.o` which should be using the `CC` so not the host. Note even if you fix that the `scripts/dtc/dtc` also fails and that looks more serious.

Comment: @Jester Can you please advise how to fix them?